# using one array to filter another array

Tags: php, arrays

I was just wondering if php had built in functions to filter an array based on the key of another array?

array 1 - is a list of all users and their basic info

array 2 - contains a meeting schedule with the users id's

e.g.

```
array 1 [0]([user_id], [name], [age], [contact]), 
        [1]([user_id], [name], [age], [contact])
        etc.

array 2 [0]([user_id], [time], [date], [place])
        [1]([user_id], [time], [date], [place])
```

Is there a way to filter array 1 so that it only contains the rows that correspond to the [user_id] in array 2.

I understand that I could use loops and custom functions to achieve this however, I just wanted to see if there was a simple way.

Thanks

Comment: You mean like array_merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided it's much easier to just use 2 loops.

The first one to create an array of the [user_id]'s and the second one to use in_array like, so:

```
$user_id = array();
foreach($users as $id){
    $user_id[]= $id['user_id'];
}
$names = array();
foreach ($schedule as $name){
    if(in_array($name['id'], $user_id)) $names[] = $name;
}
```

Too simple to bother looking for a php function.

Answer (score 2):

```
array_intersect_key($array1, $array2)
```

[PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)

code:

```
$array1 = array('user1'=> array('name'=>'name1','age' => 'age1'),
                'user2'=> array('name'=>'name2','age' => 'age2'),
                'user3'=> array('name'=>'name3','age' => 'age3'));

//array with key to search for
$array2 = array('user2'=> array('time'=>'time2','date' => 'date2'));     
echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_intersect_key($array1,$array2));
echo '</pre>';

o/p:

    Array
(
    [user2] => Array
        (
            [name] => name2
            [age] => age2
        )

)
```

edit:

Ah got your problem. If you want to manipulate your given array as per the above structure and then apply array_intersect_key(), you can do this:

```
function compare($key1,$key2){
    global $array1,$array2;

    if($array1[$key1]['userid'] == $array2[$key2]['userid'])
        return 0;
    if($array1[$key1]['userid'] > $array2[$key2]['userid'])
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}

$array1 = array(array('userid'=>'user1','name'=>'name1','age' => 'age1'),
                array('userid'=>'user2','name'=>'name2','age' => 'age2'),
                array('userid'=>'user3','name'=>'name3','age' => 'age3'));

//array with key to search for
$array2 = array(array('userid'=>'user2','time'=>'time2','date' => 'date2'));     

echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_intersect_ukey($array1,$array2,'compare'));
echo '</pre>';

o/p:
====
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [userid] => user2
            [name] => name2
            [age] => age2
        )

)
```

Comment: is does seem to be working however, the [user_id] is off by one?!

Comment: didnt get u? can u illustrate?

Comment: the schedule [user_id]=24, the result from array_intersect_key showed [user_id]=23.

Comment: It's because it's technically a multidimensional array, so it's using the index of the rows rather than the key [user_id].

Comment: here's a link: [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9f493d5b9383f20d1a4d4ee782fde73a5bc3b154) The first array is using array_insersect_key, the second is the main list, the third is the schedule that i want to use to filter the second array.

Comment: thanks for all your help! In the end I just went with two foreach loops. I know I said in the question about not using loops, however, it ended up being that simple that it didn't matter. I posted my answer below. Thanks again! :)